# Navigation Drawer Toggle not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

This question might have been asked many times, but none of the solutions are working for me.

I have an activity that implements navigation drawer but the drawer toggle button is not working.

I don't know what I am missing, but it is really bothering me.

```
package com.hajiri.jolly;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        );

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar" android:id="@+id/appbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Main layout -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.hajiri.jolly.StudentFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_school"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar" />

        <!-- Nav drawer -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit** 
It seems that the buttons on action bar are not working altogether. Even the overflow button does not responds to clicks

Comment: What about it isn't working? Does it show up? Does the button appear but not open the drawer? Is it just the wrong icon?

Comment: The icon is there. It just does not respond to clicks

Comment: Does your DrawerLayout have a gravity set?

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: Yup. It has `GravityCompat.START`. Also drawer works when I slide in from left. It's only the toggle button that's not working

Comment: Any progress on that?

Comment: The `appbar` layout was outside the `DrawerLayout` because of which the toolbar was not clickable and not responding to clicks. It was fixed after moving the `appbar` inside the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: @AayushSubedi my `appbar` is in `DrawerLayout` but still, it's not working, I have the same issue as yours. `Drawer` opens from slide but not by click.

Answer (score 0):

I did followings:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and it works OK.

R.id.driver_layout - is my  Layout in XML.