# Navigation Drawer toggle button not working

Tags: android, navigation, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

After searching similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725035/navigation-drawer-toggle-not-working) but not able to get results
 I have already defined a toggle button in my activity like

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and here is my xml where i have defined toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:queryHint="Search"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:focusable="false"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

here is what I am able to achieve after this
[image] [image]

As you can see I am not able to get Navigation toggle button on my toolbar
any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: complete xml https://pastebin.com/57zUmnhd

Comment: where is your drawer layout

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs check above comment I have given full xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` before you define `drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`

**EDIT:**

after i check your **app_main_layout.xml**, there's also a

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in there, i think this make it confuse because its also have a same id which is @+id/toolbar in your **activity.xml**

you have to change the id, or remove it, and its solved.

Comment: not working it was initial implementation after that i put `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` at bottom

Comment: wait, let me try your xml, i think the problem is in there

Comment: can you share inside of you @layout/app_bar_main ?

Comment: thats the problem, you have to remove the appbarlayout inside of app_bar_main

Comment: it works perfectly on my device after remove the AppBarLayout and Toolbar inside app_bar_main

Comment: i got the navigation button after your edits but am getting extra button https://ibb.co/cppk9Q see here please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154435/discussion-between-kevin-adhitama-and-phpdroid).

Comment: the problem is you put your drawermenu onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Answer (score 1):

You have to **setSupportActionBar** first.

Your implementation should be like this:

```
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
  drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
  toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: not working it was initial implementation after that i put `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` at bottom

Comment: try again. Copy and use the above code that should definitely work

Comment: did with same result :(

Comment: where is your drawer layout?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code ;

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```